# My button isnt working

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="but_2" class="button">
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
</div>
<div id="but_1" class="button"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.button {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#but_1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top:20px;
}
```

My css button isn't working, it brings me to where I need to be, but it is blue and is underlined(the text in the button) I have text-decor none, but it still isnt going away.

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: We need to see your related HTML.

Comment: it should work .. maybe you are not using onclick direction but "a href"...then try: a {text-decoration: none;}

Answer (score 0):

Target the `a` element to remove the underline and change the color. You can target it with `.button a {}`

```css
.button {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#but_1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 20px;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="but_2" class="button"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
</div>
<div id="but_1" class="button"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the color would still be blue, and i spent the last half hour looking through all my code I wrote, and I am pretty sure there aren't alot of mistakes, how could I get rid of that?

Comment: @Wiz does my demo not work for you? The links are white.

Comment: it worked to get rid of the underline, but I had to change it a little for the text to be white, on my screen I had to use the 6 digit letters to make white. Thanks for the underline though, I couldn't have figured that out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific and target the a href attribute.

For example:

```
 .button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xojev64e/

Comment: Ok, thanks, I need to add a few more characters so I just wrote this

Answer (score 0):

```
a {text-decoration: none; color:#FF0000;}      shows unvisited link 
a:visited {color:#FF0000;}  shows visited link 
a:hover {color:#FF0000;}  shows mouse over link
a:active {color:#FF0000;}  show selected link
```

use all property to define you color

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not clear your browsing history of your browser. First clear you history, session, or cookie and then perform following steps.

Add following to your css file

```
.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

And add this for more attraction on mouseover

```
.button a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

Hope this will help you.. :)